# How map tuple of two array with dictionary of tuple and deal with division in map?

Tags: python-3.x

```
m1 = {(1,2): 1, (2,3): 2}
A1 = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
A2 = np.array([[2,2],[3,3]])

But 

*map(lambda x,y:m1[(x,y)],A1,A2)
```

Return can not used starred expression and map is object at 0x...

How to return a 2D array or np.array?

Expect from [[m1[(1,2),m1[(1,2)],[m1[(2,3)],m1[(2,3)]]
Return 
[[1,1],[2,2]]

And

```
def func(a,b):
 If b>0:
   Return a/b
 Else:
   Return 0

*map(lambda x,y:func(x,y),A1,A2)
```

When A2 has 0, 
Value error the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

How to return a 2D array?

A1=[[1,1],[2,2]]
A2=[[2,0],[0,0]]

Expect

[[0.5,0],[0,0]]

In python 3.6

Comment: can you give a expected output that is how your 2d array should look.

Comment: Added expected output